# How do I use Wrap Bootstrap in a JS project? I have a bootstrap theme but it isn't clear how to add it to the project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web-frontend

I am interested in adding a Wrap Bootstrap theme to a website that I am building. This is my first time using a theme. It is not clear how I should add the theme to my project. I am using sublime. I will be using JS and React to build. Any guidance will be helpful.

https://wrapbootstrap.com/

Comment: Please specify your question and show us what you have tried so far. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Almost every theme is different on how to integrate within your project/site but every theme I have purchased has come with a good amount of documentation.

**The best way to get information on how to use your purchased theme is by reading the documentation that came with it.**